# Animation on a door

Tags: c#

I've been studying c sharp as part of my games course and my teacher has left and they cant find a replacement so I'm really struggling with coding my demo game. I’ve got a problem with my doors in my game and I was wondering if anyone knew how u can get it to work because I haven’t really got a clue when it comes to coding. Basically what I’ve got is my doors are shut then when I start my game they open and then shut but I need a code that will make sure it says shut until I’m in the trigger point but all the YouTube clips haven't been working and it says it’s got problems with it. I know what I want it to do I just don’t know how to put that into action.

This is my code but I don't think it does anything:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class  DoorAnimation: MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;
    int isOpeningHash;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        isOpeningHash = Animator.StringToHash("isOpening");

        bool isOpening = animator.GetBool(isOpeningHash);
        bool OpenPressed = Input.GetKey("e");
        bool CloseDoor = Input.GetKey("left shift");

        if (!isOpening && OpenPressed)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isOpeningHash, true);
        }

        if (isOpening && OpenPressed)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isOpeningHash, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is Unity, please tag it as `[unity3d]` so that we know, and so that the right people see it.

Comment: *"I've been studying c sharp as part of my games course... if anyone knew how u can get it to work because I haven’t really got a clue when it comes to coding... all the YouTube clips haven't been working"* At the risk of stating the obvious, but the goal of a games course is **not** to produce a working game but to **teach you how to program games**. If they taught you that game programming works by copying code from YouTube clips without fully understanding it, you might want to consider switching to a different educational institution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make 2 animations(and turn off the loop or it will loop for eternity) for the opening and closing of door. Don't make Bools for the animator. It's basically useless. At the top of a script declare a bool called as open and set it equal to false(if the door is closed from start). Check if E is pressed and open is set to false(the door is closed), play the opening animation, set open to true and if left shift is pressed and open is set to true(the door is open) play the closing animation, set open to false. You can play animations if a certain key is pressed like this https://answers.unity.com/questions/1362883/how-to-make-an-animation-play-on-keypress-unity-ga.html
This should do your job :)

Comment: Thank you for the help I managed to get it working now but I made it with a trigger instead to make it more simple as its a demo. Sorry for the late reply back. Also I want to then apply this animation to all my doors is their a way of doing this so that I wont have to make different animations because of the position in the animation??

Comment: You should use prefabs https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html#:~:text=Unity's%20Prefab%20system%20allows%20you,See%20in%20Glossary.